# Find missing keys in a file from a list of keys in a file

Tags: bash, shell

So, I have a `keys.txt` file that list each key (one per line) e.g.

```
VIEW_ACCOUNT_NAME_LABEL  
VIEW_ACCOUNT_NAME_DESCR  
VIEW_ACCOUNT_STREET_LABEL  
VIEW_ACCOUNT_CITY_SUBURB_LABEL  
VIEW_ACCOUNT_ZIP_POSTCODE_LABEL  
VIEW_ACCOUNT_COUNTRY_LABEL
```

And a variety of matching language files, that provide values for the keys, like this `en-GB.view.acccount.ini` which have one entry per line, like this:

```
VIEW_ACCOUNT_NAME_LABEL="Name:"
VIEW_ACCOUNT_NAME_DESCR="Name of the account holder."
VIEW_ACCOUNT_STREET_LABEL="Street:"
VIEW_ACCOUNT_CITY_SUBURB_LABEL="City/Suburb:"
VIEW_ACCOUNT_ZIP="Zip Code"
VIEW_ACCOUNT_COUNTRY_LABEL="Country"
```

*n.b. there are many key and language files, and actual files have a lot more entries — usually over 1000 per language.*

I need to be able to find

1. Which keys are missing from the language file (e.g. `VIEW_ACCOUNT_ZIP_POSTCODE_LABEL`)
2. Which keys are in the language file but not in the key file (usually obsolete keys such as `VIEW_ACCOUNT_ZIP`)

For the first requirement I tried using `grep` with the `-v` invert-match option but the results are not what I expected:

```
cppl ~ grep -v --file=keys.txt en-GB.view.acccount.ini
VIEW_ACCOUNT_NAME_LABEL="Name:"
VIEW_ACCOUNT_NAME_DESCR="Name of the account holder."
VIEW_ACCOUNT_STREET_LABEL="Street:"
VIEW_ACCOUNT_CITY_SUBURB_LABEL="City/Suburb:"
VIEW_ACCOUNT_ZIP="Zip Code"
cppl ~
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`comm`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?comm).

To find which keys are missing from the language file:

```
$ comm -23 <(sort keys.txt) <(cut -d= -f1 en-GB.view.acccount.ini | sort) 
VIEW_ACCOUNT_ZIP_POSTCODE_LABEL
```

To find which keys are in the language file but not in the key file:

```
$ comm -13 <(sort keys.txt) <(cut -d= -f1 en-GB.view.acccount.ini | sort)
VIEW_ACCOUNT_ZIP
```

Comment: I like it.  The use of `comm` seems more suited to this exact task than the approach I had in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not getting the same results. If I understand this correctly, both files are sorted then passed back to `comm`. The language file is passed through cut to return just the keys before sorting, so `comm` is effectively comparing two sets of keys. Which all makes perfect sense, except I'm getting this:

`cppl ~ comm -23 <(sort keys.txt) <(cut -d= -f1 en-GB.view.acccount.ini | sort)

VIEW_ACCOUNT_CITY_SUBURB_LABEL

VIEW_ACCOUNT_NAME_DESCR

VIEW_ACCOUNT_NAME_LABEL

VIEW_ACCOUNT_STREET_LABEL

VIEW_ACCOUNT_ZIP_POSTCODE_LABEL`

Comment: do you have any trailing spaces in the keys file? You will have to remove them if so. Try `comm -23 <(sed 's/ *//g' keys.txt | sort) <(cut -d= -f1 en-GB.view.acccount.ini | sort) `

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard unix utilities `join` and `uniq` to do this.  Here's one way to do it.

I'll assume your key file is named `file1` in the following examples.

Produce files that just contain the keys, not the values.

`sed 's/=.*//' en-GB.view.acccount.ini > file2`

You now have `file1` and `file2` containing just keys.  For this example:

```
$ cat file1
A
B
C
D

$ cat file2
C
D
E
```

You can now use a combination of `join`, `sort` and `uniq` to get your desired output.

```
# Keys which are common to both files.
$ join file1 file2 | cat - file1 | sort | uniq -d
C
D

# Keys in file1 but not in file2
$ join file1 file2 | cat - file1 | sort | uniq -u
A
B

# Keys in file2 but not in file1
$ join file1 file2 | cat - file2 | sort | uniq -u
E
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use perl for this?  If so, perl makes this super easy.  Here's a quick-and-dirty script I whipped up.  Modify to suit your tastes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# usage:  validate keys.txt file1.ini [file2.ini [file3.ini [...]]]

open my $keys_file, "<", $ARGV[0] or die "cannot open $ARGV[0] for reading";

my %keys = ( map { chomp; s/\s//g; $_ => 0 } <$keys_file> );

close $keys_file;

sub validate_file
{
    my $filename = shift @_;
    my (@missing, @unexpected, @repeated);
    my %seen = %keys;

    open my $f, "<", $filename or die "cannot open $filename for reading";

    foreach my $line (<$f>)
    {
        chomp $line;

        if ($line =~ /\s*([^=]+)="[^"]*"/)
        {
            if (!defined $seen{$1})
            {
                push @unexpected, $1;
                $seen{$1} = 0;
            }
            $seen{$1}++;
        }
    }

    @missing  = grep { $seen{$_} == 0 } sort keys %keys;
    @repeated = grep { $seen{$_} >  1 } sort keys %keys;

    return \@missing, \@unexpected, \@repeated;
}


shift @ARGV;

foreach my $file (@ARGV)
{
    my ($missing, $unexpected, $repeated) = validate_file($file);

    print "\nFile $file:\n";
    print "Missing keys:\n", join("\n", @$missing), "\n";
    print "Unexpected keys:\n", join("\n", @$unexpected), "\n";
    print "Repeated keys:\n", join("\n", @$repeated), "\n";
}
```